# Basic auth for rails5-api app in inherit controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my app I've got `ApiController < ActionController::API` which has a lot of useful methods therefore all other controllers inherit from `ApiController` instead of directly `ActionController::API`. I need to have some basic auth for webhook controller so based on [docs][1] I've got something like below:

```
class Api::V1::WebhooksController < ApiController
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic::ControllerMethods
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods

  http_basic_authenticate_with name: Rails.application.credentials.webhook_auth_name, password: Rails.application.credentials.webhook_auth_password
```

when I try to make a request I get an error:
`401 Unauthorized`

If I change the inherit to be like:

```
class Api::V1::WebhooksController < ActionController::API
```

Everything works but I don't have useful methods from `ApiController` which are essential.

I tried to include all ActionController here:

```
class ApiController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic::ControllerMethods
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods
```

But that doesn't work either.

[EDIT]

I was trying to implement other method:

```
class Api::V1::WebhooksController < ApiController

  before_action :http_basic_authenticate

# some code ...


  private

  def http_basic_authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
      username == Rails.application.credentials.webhook_auth_name &&
        password == Rails.application.credentials.webhook_auth_password
    end
  end
end
```

Which gives me - `NoMethodError authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic`

Comment: What makes you think this is an inheritance issue? If were, I would expect to see a `NoMethod` error or something like that. `401 Unauthorized` suggests (to me) that something is amiss with your logic (you're expecting `http_basic_authenticate` to return something truthy and it apparently is not).

Comment: @jvillian sorry, for last method I've received no method error - question updated